# How to execute methods in a class using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, methods, python-class

I recently found the SeleniumIDE extension for Google Chrome, but there is something I don't understand...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class TestStealth():
 def setup_method(self, method):
 print("setup_method")
 self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 self.vars = {}

def teardown_method(self, method):
 self.driver.quit()

def test_stealth(self):
 print("Testing")
 self.driver.get("https://stealthxio.myshopify.com/products/stealthxio-practice")
 self.driver.set_window_size(968, 1039)
```

this is the code I get from selenium, when I try to run with:

```
run = TestStealth()
run.setup_method()
run.test_stealth()
```

I get an error in run.setup_method() as:

```
Missing 1 required positional argument: 'method'
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `run.setup_method("ac")`

Comment: What do you not understand? The error is telling you exactly what is wrong, you are missing a required argument, `method`. Note, you *don't do anything with that*, so it seems you should just omit that from the definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message...

```
Missing 1 required positional argument: 'method'
```

...implies that the `setup_method()` is missing a required positional argument, i.e. 'method'

---

### Analysis

You were pretty close. As per the defination of `setup_method(self, method)` it expects an argument as *method*.

```
def setup_method(self, method):
```

But when you invoked `setup_method()` as in:

```
run.setup_method()
```

You haven't passed any argument. Hence there was a argument mismatch and you see the error.

---

### Solution

To execute your tests with in the *Class* using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  class TestStealth():
      def setup_method(self):
          print("setup_method")
          self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
          self.vars = {}

      def teardown_method(self):
         self.driver.quit()

      def test_stealth(self):
         print("Testing")
         self.driver.get("https://stealthxio.myshopify.com/products/stealthxio-practice")
         self.driver.set_window_size(968, 1039)    

  run = TestStealth()
  run.setup_method()
  run.test_stealth()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  setup_method

  DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51558/devtools/browser/88bf2c58-10da-4b03-9697-eec415197e66
  Testing
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: stealth]